# using results of db select (in list<string>) to compile a new intent to change class

Tags: android, android-intent

Apologies, am new to android, so this may be a very silly question. 

Would really appreciate any help though.

In android I have a table in a db which updates based upon some stuff that a user does. Based upon the content of that table I then decide what page (or class with a layout) in my app that I want the user to see next.

So for example, if the table says the user is male and 60, I know I want the user to see 'page' 2 next. If the user is female and 20, I want them to see 'page' 3 next.

I have succesfully created a simple select query which pulls back the 'page' number I want to go to next (my page numbers are the same as my class names). It pulls it back as a `list<string>` (with only one value).

My question is, how do I load a class based upon the results of this query?

i.e. in myonclicklistener how do I compile my NEXTCLASS based on the value held in my list?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NEXTCLASS.class);
startActivity(myIntent);#
```

Im sorry this is a terrible question - any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use intent filter and start activitites view intent with action (`public Intent (String action)` ). You can declare [intent filter](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) in manifest file for each "page" activity. You can create string, which first part - is yours package name, and second part - the data which you get from database.

```
List<String> dbResultList = // get data from db        
String first = "my.package.";
String dbResult = dbResultList.get(0); // for example "PAGE_3" is the value, returned from db
```

Then create intent with `new Intent(first+dbResult)` - an activity which has an intent with action `my.package.PAGE_3` in manifest should start.

Of course you should write class and layout for each page (of course if every page has it own logic and interface)